# Is there any solution to this indefinite integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How to solve the following indefinite integral?
$$
\int \frac{\lambda \alpha t^\alpha}{(1+\lambda t^{\alpha})^2}dt
$$
where $\lambda,\alpha$ are real numbers.

I've tried to integration by part, however I came across $\int \frac{1}{1+\lambda t^\alpha}dt$, which I still couldn't solve.

So, can anybody give me a hint? Big thanks!

Comment: I didn't compute it but according to WolframAlpha there doesn't seem to be a nice closed solution but this kind of integral is expressed as the Hypergeometric Function $_2 F_1$, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html . Not really a satisfying answer but to be exact 
$$\int \frac{1}{1+λ t^α} dt = t_2 F_1 (1, \frac{1}{α}; 1+\frac{1}{α}; -t^α \lambda) + \text{constant}$$
see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Clambda+t%5E%5Calpha%7Ddt

Comment: Thanks a lot...It turns out that I have to R or Matlab to obtain a numerical outcome. Your answer is very helpful.